# How to go around the push limit when pushing a merged repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, push

I have merged many repositories into one big super project using this routine:

```
git remote add -f SmallRepoX SmallRepoXRemoteURL
git merge SmallRepoX/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git add .
git commit "Added Project X"
...
git remote add -f SmallRepoY SmallRepoYRemoteURL
git merge SmallRepoY/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git add .
git commit "Added Project Y"
.
.
. 
etc
```

I would like to push this super project to a remote server. We use Visual Studio Team Services, which has a push limit of 5 GB. So I am trying to do the push in parts using this routine:

Assume history is:

> A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J

Then I do:

```
git push origin A:refs/heads/master
git push origin D:refs/heads/master
git push origin G:refs/heads/master
git push origin J:refs/heads/master
...
```

However, on the second push I get this error:

```
 ! [rejected]              D -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'RemoteSuperProURL'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And when I do `git pull`, it says everything is up to date:

```
From RemoteSuperProURL:
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

What to do?

**EDIT:**

Git status:

```
C:\Users\..>git status
On branch MyBranch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Log:

```
C:\Users\..>git log D..origin/master --oneline
A (origin/master) A-Commit-Message

C:\Users\..>git log origin/master..D --oneline
D D-Commit-Message
B B-Commit-Message
A A-Commit-Message
```

Notice that C commit is missing. Maybe that is since the history is the result of merge?

Comment: Can you show the output of the below commands: `git status`, `git log D..origin/master --oneline` and `git log origin/master..D --oneline`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT See edit please.

Comment: It seems the commit history not as liner. Instead there may contains some orphan commits. Can you also show the commit history as graph by `gitk --all`?